# How do I pass normal telephone line(s) threw a LAN?

Tags: tcp, voip, lan

I would like to pass 1 or more telephone lines to a distant location threw a tcp/ip connection (lan) and export the line(s) threw some equipment to normal phones (no ip phones).

So there should be something like this:

line --- equipment --- wifi ---equipment---- normal phone.

I am working on networks but never worked on voip or anything like that.
So I would like to know what kind of equipment (except lan equipment) should I use in order to achieve it
Thank you.

Comment: Well, this question does not belong here at all. -Having said that -  If I understood your question, you need a VoIP gateway,an element which takes in ISDN lines via E1/T1 links or analog lines and packages the voice packets into TCP/IP packets. The gateway can do the reverse as well. Some protocols like SIP come into picture. Lots  of reference are out there. Google for VoIP. SIP /RTCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an FXO box (for first equipment) and an FXS box for second one. There are lots of such devices as well as routers' modules. You need them both to support the same VoIP protocol, most probably SIP or H323.

Then you need to configure FXO to pass all incoming calls directly to FXS's ip address and FXS to pass all calls directly to FXO's.

Later you can add some IP pbx between them to implement more advanced call routing schemes.